# wash rule applicability between regular and retirement accounts

Tags: income-tax

I have a regular brokerage account and a retirement brokerage account.

Suppose that I actively trade in both accounts in a given tax year.

I know that at tax time, my broker will generate two independent forms, one for each account, and consider the wash rule within each account.

Am I on the hook for considering the wash rule between the two accounts, even if one of them is a retirement account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.bankrate.com/investing/wash-sale-rule/

"You may not sell an asset for a loss in a taxable account and then re-buy the asset inside a retirement account such as a 401(k) or an IRA within the 30-day window and still claim a loss in the taxable account."

This is consistent with the advice found at several other financial websites.

Answer (score 0):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Am I on the hook for considering the wash rule between the two
> accounts, even if one of them is a retirement account?

The wash rule treats non-retirement accounts and retirement accounts separately. A trade in a retirement account can't wash with a trade in a non-retirement account.

Comment: I defer to the answer by FlanMan which suggests that my conclusion was overstated and missed the scenario contemplated in his answer.